# What is the purpose of Unit-Testing in a simple CRUD front-end application?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, language-agnostic, crud

This might be a broad question, but in general, why is it important to unit test in a CRUD front-end. Imagine I have a CRUD server written using Node.js, and I black-box tests for all the endpoints that the backend API offers. Having this, is there a necessity to implement some kind of unit-test in let's say an iOS client? If so what kinds of things can be tested and what should not be tested?

Answer (score 0):

You could write unit tests for cases that may deal with no connectivity, bad data, internal server error (which is now thrown to you) etc